# how can I remove credit card payment option from PayPal Plus's payment selection page

Tags: php, paypal

I have implemented Paypal Plus that is working fine. But as per paypal plus its showing payment selection option wall that is showing by default three options - 
1 - paypal
2 - Direct debit
3 - credit card

I want only paypal to be there. So, how can I remove credit card payment option from PayPal Plus's payment selection page ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwllA.png)

Comment: Hey, have you ever found a solution to this? If you did, could you enlight us?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try contacting the PayPal customer care. I don't think you can configure it from within the account.

Comment: I don't thing so, there should be some variable that we need to pass in API to fix this. Anyway thx for replying.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `fundingSource` parameter. Example:

```
var button = paypal.Buttons({
            fundingSource: paypal.FUNDING.PAYPAL,
            createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
              return actions.subscription.create({
                'plan_id': 'P-2U932934TF985691ALZ3HLEF'
              });
            },
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
              alert('You have successfully created subscription ' + data.subscriptionID);
            }
        });

        // Check if the button is eligible
        if (button.isEligible()) {

            // Render the standalone button for that funding source
            button.render('#paypal-button-container');
        }
```

This link might also be of help: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/standalone-buttons/